# How to deal with under-performing teammate when boss doesn't notice?

Tags: management, colleagues, performance

I work in a small company but my team has currently grown to include well over a dozen people. We all report to the same boss.

This big team is broken up into sub-teams (each sub-team has no manager). One of the sub-teams is myself and this other new guy (I have been with the company for years, but he was hired only a few months ago).

It *seems* to me that new guy is under-performing. He takes weeks to complete certain projects which I can do in days or hours. I don't know if this is because he is not as experienced as me or because he is lazy/slacking or both.

Our boss is always super busy, so I am not sure if he is even aware of new guy's under performance or if he knows but accepts it (we were trying for a while to hire for his position).

How should I being the "senior" person on his sub-team handle this situation? I am not technically his manager so I find it hard to talk to him directly about the quality of his work, at the same time I don't want to go to my boss, because again it is not supposed to be my job to keep tabs on him.

Yet I feel a moral obligation to do something about what I believe is his sub-par performance.

How best should this be handled?

Also in this company, we don't do performance reviews so I don't know if anyone will ever come to know if I don't say anything.

Comment: What you describe as "sub-par performance" doesn't seem to be impacting you or your firm.  You just think he should be working faster.  As you said, it's not your job to keep an eye on him and he doesn't report to you, so you don't know the full story in any case.

Comment: Whole company seems 'sub par'

Answer (score 1):

Totally Astonished to read about a company having no performance reviews of his workers and production target. In my service I haven't see such organization.  Moreover, I could not understand that if there is no check & balance in company for his employees and production than how it is functional and achieving  the production target.

Being a senior colleague in company it is your obligatory duty to trained him regarding each task and give him targeted task to achieve in certain time frame. Also give some time frame as probation period and tell him if he will not improve his performance, his  case will be taken up in front of boss.

In our organization for each newcomer we assign one instructor from senior lot to trained him and monitor his training regularly. During three month probation if we find the person under performer we terminate him.

Even after your attempt he did not perform than  it your moral duty to approach to boss and tell him regarding his performance.  I have no doubt that he will ultimately   warned him to improve and will take appropriate disciplinary action

Comment: This is completely true.   But the central issue seems to just be that OP won't "speak up".  Just speak up.  "You're not 13 years old!"

Answer (score -6):

"It's not high school",

simply openly and bluntly, at all times (40 times a day) loudly state sentences such as

> "You seem to be not even close to the skill level needed here"

And for your boss, simply openly and bluntly, at all times (40 times a day) loudly state sentences such as

> "Boss, we have no leadership at all, all work is in chaos, and a number of members like Biff here are doing nothing whatsoever."

Just speak up.

It's not high school. You're all there to make money and then go home to your families.

You *have to* excise useless team members, or *everyone* will go down.

Comment: Regardless of the skill level of a colleague, making statements like that could easily be seen as creating a hostile work environment.  And such behavior should be shut down, possibly with the person making such statements being excised.